# comparing values of two different hashmaps based on their key in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two different hashmaps. Now I need to compare the hashmaps based on their keys.Like,

```
HashMap1:
Key: BOF   Value: SAPF,754
Key: BOM   Value: SAPM,456
Key: BOL   Value: SAPL,987


HashMap2:
Key: LOF   Value: YTR,654
Key: BOL   Value: UHG,732
```

Now I want to compare all those entries in the hashmaps whose 'key's are same and return the difference between the second index  of 'values' String[]

Like here it should return:
Key: BOL   Value: SAPL,255

(as 987-732=255)

How to do it?

Comment: Iterate the `Map.entrySet()` of each map to find the key(s) corresponding to the value.

Comment: iterators and loops will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map.keySet()` will return set of keys in map. Then you have to get value with this key from both map and find the difference.

```
Map<String, String[]> mp1 = //
Map<String, String[]> mp2 = //
Map<String, List<String>> res = new HashMap<>();
for (String key : mp1.keySet()) {
    int val1 = Integer.valueOf(mp1.get(key)[1]);
    int val2 = Integer.valueOf(mp2.get(key)[1]);
    List<String> resVal = new ArrayList<>();
    resVal.add(mp1.get(key)[0]);
    resVal.add(String.valueOf(val1-val2));
    res.put(key, resVal);
}
return res;
```

One more thing, you have check for existence. Otherwise you will get `NullPointerException`

Comment: Hi Emdadul,just a thing to ask...here you are returning only the difference of the corresponding entry.But i want the entire entry

Comment: no, mp1.get(key) will return value (String[]). Then I am taking value from index 1 by mp1.get(key)[1]. See the index here.

Comment: what i am trying to say is in that arraylist u are adding val1-val2 right? like (987-732)=255..so u are adding 255. But the i want the entire entry like:     Key: BOL Value: SAPL,255

Comment: Ohh, then create a new Map to store result. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)